# float[] difference

Tags: java

I'm wonder what's the most efficient way to find the the absolute value of the difference between two float arrays?

Is it the following:

```
private float absDifference(float[] vector1, float[] vector2) {
    float difference=0;
    int len=Math.max(vector1.length, vector2.length);
    for(int n=0;n<len;n++){
        float diff=0;
        if(n<vector1.length){
            diff+=vector1[n];
        }
        if(n<vector2.length){
            diff-=vector2[n];
        }
        difference+=Math.abs(diff);
    }
    return difference;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private float absDifference(float[] vector1, float[] vector2) {
    float difference=0;
    int len=Math.min(vector1.length, vector2.length);
    for(int n=0;n<len;n++){
            diff+=vector1[n]-vector2[n];
        difference+=Math.abs(vector1[n]-vector2[n]);
    }
    if(vector1.length > vector2.length){
        for(;n<vector1.length;n++){
            difference+=Math.abs(vector1[n]);
       }
    }else{
       for(;n<vector2.length;n++){
           difference+=Math.abs(vector2[n]);
       }
    }
    return difference;
}
```

this way there is no repeated bounds check inside first loop after that the rest of the longer array is handled separately

Comment: I changed your code so that it compiled and it was faster thanks.

Comment: You can ommit the `if` and `else` and simply put both for loops there - one of them will be a zero-iterations loop.

Comment: Also, your `diff += ...` line is superfluous (and it likely what needed to be changed to be compilable, in addition to moving the `int n` declaration before the loop).